# How can I make a div stretch to include a contained table?

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table that is sometimes wider than the `div` it is inside – this causes my table to go outside the `div` border.

How can I make the `div` stretch so the `div` border always goes around the table?

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSELG/) shows the problem if you shrink the result pane.

```css
div#wrapper{
    margin: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>stuff</td>
            <td>stuff</td>
            <td>stuff</td>
            <td>stuff</td>
            <td>stuff</td>
            <td>stuff</td>
            <td>stuff</td>
            <td>stuff</td>
            <td>more stuff</td>
            <td>more stuff</td>
            <td>more stuff</td>
            <td>more stuff</td>
            <td>more stuff</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Looks fine in my browser. What are you using?

Comment: @DaoWen I see it breaking when I make the window smaller in Firefox 22. The black border overlaps the table instead of moving with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the `display` value of `div#wrapper` to `inline-block` is one way:

```css
div#wrapper {
    margin: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[fixed jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSELG/5/)